# Laravel changing route links based on database records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, routes

I'm building an application that schedules aircraft for flight schools/flying clubs, etc.

I currently have a schedule grid running that allows the user to click on a square to book a reservations starting at that time. That function works perfectly, however, if a single booking exists in the system, for some reason, Laravel deletes the final part of the URL, throwing a 404. Any thoughts on this? I inspected the page and it physically looks like the view is being altered, although the code clearly shows this part. See below:

When there are no records, if a user selects a box on the grid, they are directed to finalize the booking at:
`/app/schedule/new/{time}/{date}/{resource}/{instructor?}`

For example, a booking starting at 730am today with no instructor using resource #1 (plane 1) is:
`/app/schedule/new/0730/20201204/1`

However, when there is a booking in the system, all boxes on the grid point to
`/app/schedule/new/{time}/{date}`

Or, in our example:
`/app/schedule/new/0730/20201204` (this is incorrect, there should be a `/1` at the end)

Here is my route:

`Route::get('/app/schedule/new/{time}/{date}/{resource}/{instructor?}', 'ScheduleController@show_new_booking_form');`

And the view href which points to the correct link (instructor is optional):

`<a href="/app/schedule/new/0730/{{$raw_date}}/{{$aircraft->aircraft_id}}">`

(Edited) Complete steps for all this to happen.

1. User visits the bookings page with the schedule grid. This is where they would select the link from above. The controller method for that is:

```
public function show_schedule(Request $request)
    {
        // Reference Variables
        $days = $request->days;
        $org_id = Auth::user()->org;

        // Information on Dates & Date Incremation
        $today = Carbon::now('US/Eastern');
        $date = $today->addDays($days);
        $schedule_date = $date->isoFormat('dddd MMMM D, YYYY');
        $raw_date = $date->isoFormat('YYYYMMDD');
        
        $aircraft = DB::table('aircraft')->where('org', $org_id)->get(); // gets all aircraft for this organization
        $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->where('org', $org_id)->get();

        // Grid date info
        $grid_date = $date->isoFormat('YYYY-MM-DD');

        return view('schedule/schedule')->with(compact('raw_date','schedule_date', 'days', 'aircraft','bookings','grid_date'));
    }
```

Then, they are presented with a form where they finish the booking if they are rerouted correctly. The view for the main schedule grid consists of a foreach loop to break the collection of aircraft into individual records:

```
@foreach ($aircraft as $aircraft)
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{$aircraft->type}}">{{ $aircraft->aircraft_n }}</th>
            <td class="sh-td"><a href="/app/schedule/new/0700/{{$raw_date}}/{{$aircraft->aircraft_id}}"><div class="td-clickable"></div></a></td>
```

... this continues for all times until 830pm (each gets it's own td)

Comment: did you checked if {{$aircraft->aircraft_id}} is not null/empty in your view?

Comment: @ManojSalvi the variable isn't null; it works fine when there are no records. The aircraft table isn't changing when I add/remove bookings.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code of the controller func as well where you are grabbing the $aircraft for a better understanding of why the 1( "aircraft_id") is missing in the specific scenario when their is a record in the table.

Comment: @ManojSalvi  Sure thing -- post is updated. Let me know if you'd like to see anything else

Comment: from your query it seems you are getting a collection of aircrafts(not a single aircraft) so how are you expecting a single aircraft id ($aircraft->aircraft_id) from a collection??

Comment: Pls post the code for complete controller methods: 1. to show the bookings page 2. once a user clicks and is redirected to `/app/schedule/new/{time}/{date}/{resource}/{instructor?}

`  - controller method handling how request is being redirected to the bookings page

Comment: are you displaying the collection with a loop?? Please post more code as @Donkarnash pointed.

Comment: The collection is being displayed as a loop and the post has been updated. Thanks again -- sorry for the confusion here there are a lot of moving pieces.

Comment: just pluralize the $aircraft collection to $aircrafts in controller and views as well to avoid confusion.

Comment: `@foreach ($aircraft as $aircraft)` that ain't right

Comment: Also, assuming you have relationships set up reasonably, you could greatly simplify this code like `$aircraft = Auth::user()->org->aircrafts; $bookings = Auth::user()->org->bookings;`

Comment: You made a big mistake with your naming conventions here. Table name should be plural of model, and model should be an unambigously singular name.